# Bash: How to read password from stdin without echoing over SSH

Tags: bash, ssh, sudo

I have the following script, which works:

```
echo -n "Enter sudo password: "
read -s sudo_pass
echo "$sudo_pass" | ssh -tt myhost "sudo -S ./remote_script.sh"
```

The problem is the output. I'd like the password from `stdin` to be used by `sudo`, but NOT be printed to the screen. Instead, I get:

```
<system banner>

thepassw0rd
[sudo] password for theuser:
```

Is there a way to accomplish this? I'm not even sure which command is causing the input to be printed.

#### UPDATE

I was able to find that the input is being printed by ssh by just doing:

```
echo 123 | ssh -tt myhost "sleep 2"
```

which gave me

```
<system banner>

123
Connection to myhost closed.
```

Comment: Why not just let `sudo` prompt the user for the password?

Comment: @chepner I am, at the beginning of the script. This script is dumbed down significantly for brevity here. The last line is actually part of a loop over many servers that have the same sudo password, and I only want to prompt my user once.

Comment: You should consider configuring `sudo` to allow an appropriate user to run the command without a password.

Comment: @chepner I completely agree with you. But changing the `sudo` configuration in this scenario is completely out of the question, unfortunately.

Comment: Are you using `-tt` because `remote_script.sh` requires a pseudotty, or because you think `sudo` does?

Comment: If I'm being totally honest on that one, I'd have to say, "because the internet said so." Right before I saw your comment, I tried `-T` instead and it worked. Thanks!

Comment: `-T` probably isn't necessary; it's the default, and is probably used to override a setting in (e.g.) an SSH configuration file.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem here lies with the `-tt` option to `ssh`. You are forcing it to allocate a pseudo-terminal. This pseudo-terminal reads stdin and doesn't know whether what it reads comes from your keyboard or a redirection (`echo "$sudo_pass" | ssh ...`). So it acts like a terminal and echoes what it receives (because it receives it before `sudo` has the time to run and capture stdin).

You are experiencing one of the drawbacks of the `-t` option. Another one that hasn't hit you yet is that if your password starts with an `ssh` escape sequence (`~C`, `~?`, etc) this won't work as expected either.

Easy and best solution: do not use the `-tt` option.

If you really cannot do without it - because e.g. your remote script adamantly wants a terminal - one (ugly) solution would be to "eat" the first line that is sent back by `ssh`, since you know for sure it will always be your password that is echoed back:

```
echo "$sudo_pass" | ssh -tt myhost ... | ( read; cat )
```

Personally, I wouldn't be so sure that the first line would always be the password and I don't recommend this. A far better alternative, is to add a small delay before sending the password, in order to let `sudo` start remotely and capture stdin:

```
( sleep 1; echo "$sudo_pass" ) | ssh -tt myhost ...
```

But this still is a hack and the best solution is of course to not use `ssh`'s `-tt` option.

Comment: Its worth noting the `-S` flag for `sudo` is still required, its just the `-tt` flag for `ssh` that should be removed.

Comment: Absolutely @Shane, this is a generic answer. As demonstrated by the OP in his question, the problem is independent of sudo. BTW thank you for your edit.